# Moved partitions slow to boot on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I'm starting a community Linux hobbyist group.  Along with a Pi and an AWS server, I have an old laptop with a Core2Duo 2.2GHz and 6GB DDR2 to demo stuff with.  For added oomph, I've installed a 240GB SSD.  It's a BIOS system, not UEFI.  Everything is 64bit.

Windows 10 and System Reserved are at the start, in two primary partitions.  After that, I used extended partitions and installed my favoured OS, Xubuntu, and swap.  Then, just to show that it can be done, I installed Windows 10 in VirtualBox in Xubuntu.  I added more Ubuntu flavours then decided to resize my Windows and Xubuntu partitions: more Xubuntu, less Windows, and Kubuntu and Budgie were shuffled down a bit.  I did this using gparted on a live *buntu pendrive made with UNetbootin.  Grub2 broke, so I fixed it with live pendrive and proceeded to load more flavours.  A total of five Ubuntu varieties and two Mints, with about 30GB to spare.

All the Linux OSs on moved partitions are slow to complete boot (Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Budgie), they hang during splash screen and HD activity LED goes out for a while, until it shifts and you get login screen.  OSs installed later are fine.  Ubuntu Mate, for example, boots in 15 seconds.  Xubuntu takes 1m45s.

There's barely anything on any of the installed OSs so I could just back-up my virtual Windows 10 and reload Xu, Ku and Budgie, but I'd rather find a fix :) Where would I start looking?

Comment: Can I just ask why you loaded all those OSes on one laptop? (and why you have both ku and xu...)

Comment: Check out dmesg, look for large time gaps. Also, if it's a recent release, try `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: AlinuxLover - it's a demo laptop, for a group that may include curious beginners, so I'm doing it for the heck of it and as an example to others (of how not to do things)

Comment: If you want an example of how not to do things, you're on the right track. Leave it as it is :-)

Comment: How the heck else would I ever learn????

Answer (score 1):

Being as the problem only began after you moved partitions around, it can only be that the partitions are not properly aligned. If you use `gparted` for Ext4 and swap partitions, it will make sure the partitions are aligned properly. Use Windows own Disk Management app to manage NTFS partitions.

In `terminal`...

**To quick-check if that's the problem:**

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and it will say the partitions are misaligned or not.

**However, a more accurate way is to use `parted`:**

```
sudo parted
parted> print
1 {partition 1 detail}
2 {partition 2 detail}
parted> align-check optimal 1
parted> align-check optimal 2
```

for more help `man parted`.

Comment: Alignment is only critical on partitions you write into. Since you do not directly write into the extended partition it is not normally aligned. And alignment is more importand for SSD & new 4K drives. Also make sure BIOS has AHCI on, or trim will not work.

Comment: @oldfred Please explain why alignment is only critical on partitions you write to. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The extended partition is a container, not a partition you write into. So its start is not critical. Just about every other partition is then critical. Rod Smith is the real expert, but then he is also the author of gdisk for gpt(GUID) partitioning and extended partition is not used. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-on-4kb-sector-disks/ See his comment here on extended partitions: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1685666&p=10450466#post10450466

Comment: @oldfred ah... you were referring to extended partitions! I thought that you were talking about all partitions.

Comment: thanks oldfred, I'll look at AHCIin the BIOS.  Is TRIM enabled by default in Ubuntu 17.04 and derivatives when AHCI is enabled in BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance - here's my findings!!

Discs were properly aligned, having moved them with `gparted`. Output of align-check optimal [1-12]  says aligned, except 3 (not aligned for some reason) and 4 (does not exist).  I still thought it was related to partitioning because of my odd layout - here's my parted> print output

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      525MB   86.4GB  85.9GB  primary   ntfs
 3      86.4GB  211GB   125GB   extended
 7      86.4GB  140GB   53.7GB  logical   ext4
 8      140GB   142GB   2147MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 5      142GB   156GB   13.3GB  logical   ext4
 6      156GB   167GB   11.1GB  logical   ext4
 9      167GB   178GB   11.1GB  logical   ext4
10      178GB   189GB   11.1GB  logical   ext4
11      189GB   200GB   11.1GB  logical   ext4
12      200GB   211GB   11.1GB  logical   ext4
```

I like it.  It'll be a talking point at the meet-up one day.

`dmesg` tells me `random: crng init done` occurs at the moment the system freezes and a clue came from searching the web for that string and finding Launchpad Bug #1685794.  Here they talk about problems with encrypted swap.  Since my swap isn't encrypted, I decided to have a look at my fstab anyway, see if there was a swap partition error.  Yup, UUID was wrong.

How I believe I caused this, I chose the "something else" partitioning option each install.  While creating the root partition, if I also *clicked on the swap partition*, I set a new UUID to the partition.  I guess that I just didn't do that during the last four installs.  How this relates to `random: crng init done` I think mounting fstab entries happens at the same time as `random: crng init done` whatever it is.

This was also an experiment in seeing what happens if I use one swap for multiple installs on one machine.  Now I know :)

Comment: Using only 1 swap means that you won't be able to hibernate any OS's.

Comment: Fair point, and I guessed as much.  I've never been a fan of hibernate under any OS anyway.  Thanks for the advice :)